# NameError: name 'questionTextOne' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

The variable is apparently not defined, although it has been used already.  Code is [here](https://pastebin.com/ugEFCp19)

As you can see, i tried to declare the variable as global.

Full error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Documents\Assesment.py", line 145, in incorrect
    unpackOne()
  File "C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Documents\Assesment.py", line 173, in unpackOne
    questionTextOne.pack_forget()
NameError: name 'questionTextOne' is not defined
```

Comment: there is no `questionTextOne` object in outer scope

Comment: also provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not all of your project code

Comment: please don't link to code on an external site.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `questionTextOne` as global in `unpackOne`, but no other scope shares that idea.  When `unpackOne` tries to use a pre-existing value for `questionTextOne`, there isn't one.  The only other place in the program that uses the same variable name is `ask` (see line 38), but `ask` keeps it as a separate variable.

If you want that shared with the rest of the program, tell `ask` to share it glabally.  Insert

```
global questionTextOne
```

at line 26.

Note that global variables are generally a bad idea.  You should generally pass the object from routine to routine as needed.